# Laravel Validator less than sign "<"

Tags: php, laravel

On my login form I can validate the password and username field like this

```
  $request->validate([
        $this->username() => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha'
    ]);
```

Now that I have an additional field called `login_attempts`

I need to validate if `login_attempts` field value is `less than 3`

can we do something like this on my validator

`if login_attempts < 3` ?

my table name is `users`

Comment: FYI, having login attempts sent as part of your form request will not be reliable. It is easily modified on the client side. It might be good enough for your purposes, but it is not a proper security measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule you're looking for is `lt:3`.

So just update your code above to:

```
$request->validate([
    $this->username() => 'required|string',
    'password' => 'required|string',
    'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
    'login_attempts' => 'lt:3'
]);
```

Alternatively, you can validate "less than or equal to" using `lte:3`.

See Laravel's Validation docs for more info:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-lt